# Undefined reference to 'dlopen', 'dlclose', 'dlsym' and 'dlerror' when build hsdis-amd64.dll on Windows with Cygwin64

Tags: java, windows, cygwin

With a reference from "https://dropzone.nfshost.com/hsdis/", I have encountered a mistake **undefined reference to 'dlopen', 'dlclose', 'dlerror' and 'dlsym'**.

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o build/Linux-amd64/hsdis-amd64.dll -Ibuild/Linux-amd64/include -I/home/bahuwang/binutils-2.32/include -I/home/bahuwang/binutils-2.32/bfd -Ibuild/Linux-amd64/bfd -DLIBARCH_amd64 -DLIBARCH=\"amd64\" -DLIB_EXT=\".dll\" -O hsdis.c -shared build/Linux-amd64/bfd/libbfd.a build/Linux-amd64/opcodes/libopcodes.a build/Linux-amd64/libiberty/libiberty.a build/Linux-amd64/zlib/libz.a
build/Linux-amd64/bfd/libbfd.a(plugin.o):plugin.c:(.text+0x46c)：undefined reference to 'dlopen'
build/Linux-amd64/bfd/libbfd.a(plugin.o):plugin.c:(.text+0x4a7)：undefined reference to 'dlclose'
build/Linux-amd64/bfd/libbfd.a(plugin.o):plugin.c:(.text+0x543)：undefined reference to 'dlerror'
build/Linux-amd64/bfd/libbfd.a(plugin.o):plugin.c:(.text+0x59c)：undefined reference to 'dlsym'
```

I found it can do when add a parameter "-ldl" at the end of the command, like

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o build/Linux-amd64/hsdis-amd64.dll -Ibuild/Linux-amd64/include -I/home/bahuwang/binutils-2.32/include -I/home/bahuwang/binutils-2.32/bfd -Ibuild/Linux-amd64/bfd -DLIBARCH_amd64 -DLIBARCH=\"amd64\" -DLIB_EXT=\".dll\" -O hsdis.c -shared build/Linux-amd64/bfd/libbfd.a build/Linux-amd64/opcodes/libopcodes.a build/Linux-amd64/libiberty/libiberty.a build/Linux-amd64/zlib/libz.a -idl
```

But the compiled hsdis-amd64.dll shows

```
Could not load hsdis-amd64.dll; library not loadable; PrintAssembly is disabled
```

What's the problem?

And when I make a crosscompiler on Centos 7 with command

```
make MINGW=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc BINUTILS=~/binutils-2.32
```

It works well.